# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in while loop

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, while-loop, offset

I am trying to get all of the post_ids from the followers (in the followers table) into an array

This might be a long code but here it is:

```
while (post_count($con, $session_user_id) > $n) {
$pfields = array("post_id", "from", "content", "good", "favorite"/*, "time", "date"*/);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT followed_id FROM followers WHERE user_id = $session_user_id");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $data = array();
        $data = $row;
    }
    $t = 0;
    $postids = array();
    if (empty($data) !== true && isset($data)) {
        while ($data[$t] !== NULL) { //ERROR HERE
            $sql1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE" . $data[$t] . "= from ORDER BY  posts.post_id DESC LIMIT $t, 100") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {
            $postids = array();
            $postids[] = $row[0];
            }
            $t++;
        if ($t>10) {
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE from = $session_user_id ORDER BY  posts.post_id DESC LIMIT $n, 100") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if ($sql2 === false) {
        echo "An error ocurred";
    } else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
        $postids[] = $row[0]; //ERROR HERE TOO
    }
    }
        rsort($postids); `
```

The errors shown are  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/cabox/workspace/LOL/home.php on line 55 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/cabox/workspace/LOL/home.php on line 72 
I have checked other questions and they don't answer my own. I've checked the query and they do show something in my database. Thanks!

Comment: please format correctly! I've been getting some trouble with that

Comment: Reduce that code to minimum reproducible fragment. We don't even know which is line  72 or 55.

Comment: I've put comments in the code to show where the first and second error are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, result will be formatted as an associative array. So you need to change your code like below:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
    $postids[] = $row['post_id'];
}
```

As `PHP`'s document says:

> mysqli_fetch_assoc : Fetch a result row as an associative array

Otherwise, you may need to use `mysqli_fetch_row()`.

Comment: Thanks that solved the second problem, what about the first one though?